# What is the difference between べき and べきだ

Tags: particles, copula, modality

Are べき and べきだ one and same thing?

I found many grammars where べき is defined, but examples with べきだ are provided.

知るべき。

両親には従うべきだ。

Or is だ a copula? But then why do we use a copula in such case?

Comment: The prenominal form of べきだ (i.e., the form which modifies a noun) is べき. [べきだ](https://itazuraneko.neocities.org/grammar/dojg/dojgpages/intermediate%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A0.html)

Comment: But in the example here (https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A0-beki-da-meaning/), べき comes after a verb: 知るべき

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just written that way as an example of the construction, not something you should use. All the examples use the copula when べき is in the predicate position. You can check [weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%22) to see that べき is the prenominal form.

Comment: Like in this example: 田中は全く軽蔑すべき男だ。

Comment: I find confusing that べき is said to be an inflection of べし (http://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D.html). Then why what is indexed in grammars is べき and not べし?

Comment: Presumably because べし > べき is classical grammar, but still gets used in modern Japanese. If it was modern grammar they wouldn't need to have an entry for every inflection.

Comment: Why if it was modern grammar they wouldn't need to have an entry for every inflection?

Comment: Isn't that what you were expecting? Usually there's one main entry and not one entry for every possible inflection. I'm wondering why you asked the question...